# Remix application deployment on Netlify

Tags: netlify, remix.run

So i have been tasked with deploying an already existing local remix.js application on Netlify.
The issue is that I am not familiar with Remix and from what information i have gathered is that Netlify requires a index.html file to operate whilst Remix only builds a index.js file and a "hidden" index.html file.
The deployment in itself works fine and i do not get any red flags.

I was hoping some of you might know or have experienced this issue before.

1. I added the code below into netlify.toml.

```
[build]
  command = "npm run build"
  functions = "netlify/functions" # Your functions directory
  publish = "public" # The directory with your generated assets

[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

2. I have also tried (as suggested by netlify) to make a new project through the netlify remix boilerplate and added my own files into it with no success.
3. I have also tried doing some adjustments inside the "Site configurations" on netlify.

```
Building Complete
9:54:30 AM: Netlify Build                                                 
9:54:30 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
9:54:30 AM: ​
9:54:30 AM: ❯ Version
9:54:30 AM:   @netlify/build 29.36.0
9:54:30 AM: ​
9:54:30 AM: ❯ Flags
9:54:30 AM:   baseRelDir: true
9:54:30 AM:   buildId: 65e82f1b6172db00089e7721
9:54:30 AM:   deployId: 65e82f1b6172db00089e7723
9:54:30 AM: ​
9:54:30 AM: ❯ Current directory
9:54:30 AM:   /opt/build/repo
9:54:30 AM: ​
9:54:30 AM: ❯ Config file
9:54:30 AM:   /opt/build/repo/netlify.toml
9:54:30 AM: ​
9:54:30 AM: ❯ Context
9:54:30 AM:   production
9:54:30 AM: ​
9:54:30 AM: Build command from Netlify app                                
9:54:30 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
9:54:30 AM: ​
9:54:30 AM: $ npm run build
9:54:30 AM: > build
9:54:30 AM: > pnpm codegen && remix build
9:54:31 AM: > crystallize-translation-app@ codegen /opt/build/repo
9:54:31 AM: > graphql-codegen --require dotenv/config --config codegen.ts
9:54:31 AM: [STARTED] Parse Configuration
9:54:31 AM: [SUCCESS] Parse Configuration
9:54:31 AM: [STARTED] Generate outputs
9:54:31 AM: [STARTED] Generate to ./src/__generated__/types.ts
9:54:31 AM: [STARTED] Load GraphQL schemas
9:54:33 AM: [SUCCESS] Load GraphQL schemas
9:54:33 AM: [STARTED] Load GraphQL documents
9:54:33 AM: [SUCCESS] Load GraphQL documents
9:54:33 AM: [STARTED] Generate
9:54:33 AM: [SUCCESS] Generate
9:54:33 AM: [SUCCESS] Generate to ./src/__generated__/types.ts
9:54:33 AM: [SUCCESS] Generate outputs
9:54:34 AM:  info  building... (NODE_ENV=production)
9:54:36 AM:  info  built (1.9s)
9:54:36 AM: ​
9:54:36 AM: (build.command completed in 5.7s)
9:54:36 AM: ​
9:54:36 AM: (Netlify Build completed in 5.9s)
9:54:37 AM: Section completed: building
9:55:09 AM: Finished processing build request in 1m8.747s

//

Deploying Complete
9:54:36 AM: Deploy site                                                   
9:54:36 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
9:54:36 AM: ​
9:54:36 AM: Starting to deploy site from "build"
9:54:36 AM: Calculating files to upload
9:54:36 AM: 0 new files to upload
9:54:36 AM: 0 new functions to upload
9:54:36 AM: Section completed: deploying
9:54:36 AM: Site deploy was successfully initiated
9:54:36 AM: ​
9:54:36 AM: (Deploy site completed in 149ms)
9:54:36 AM: ​
9:54:36 AM: The build completed successfully, but the following processes were still running:
9:54:36 AM: ​
9:54:36 AM:    - /opt/build/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/@esbuild+linux-x64@0.17.6/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-x64/bin/esbuild --service=0.17.6 --ping
9:54:36 AM: ​
9:54:36 AM: These processes have been terminated. In case this creates a problem for your build, refer to this article for details about why this process termination happens and how to fix it.
```